# How to include a list of files, each with a virtual resource declaration

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

In my Puppet (2.6) module definition, I create user accounts by declaring them as virtual resources; today they take the form `@useraccount('name'=>'joe')` and `@useraccount('name'=>'mary')` within a single class, which then gets `include`-ed when I want to realize them all (i.e. `include useraccounts` followed by `Useraccount <| |>`).

I would like to move these individual `@useraccount` definitions into separate files so I can better manage users individually. But it doesn't appear that the `include` command allows for a wildcard (i.e. `include useraccounts/*` where I would then maintain one file per user in the `useraccounts` subdir)

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use import:

If you put this in seperate files in manifests/users/*.pp, you can import it by including this in your site.pp:

```
import "users/*.pp"
```

Kind regards,
Ger.